# Creating all zeros except one nonzero element in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create an M*N tensor where all elements are all zeros except one random element per row which shall be one but I don't know how.

Comment: Maybe you can simply create a [tf.zeros](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros) tensor and then randomly set one number to 1 using [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) ? I'm just giving you hints I didn't try it.

Comment: @Hugo That's one possibility, but only if the values are variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = 4
n = 6
dt = tf.float32
random_idx = tf.random_uniform((m, 1), maxval=n, dtype=tf.int32)
result = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.range(n)[tf.newaxis], random_idx), dtype=dt)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks but in your output only one element is 1. What I need one element per row randomly be 1.

Comment: @MikeFelan Oh, right, I didn't read that right, fixed it now.